# how to sort a PHP generated list of pictures

Tags: php, sorting

i am using Dynamic PHP Picture Viewer (v1.0) by JavaScriptKit.com, and my issue is that the images listed aren't in any kind of order, be it numerical, alphabetical, or date created/modified/added. it's nice not having to type up the images individual (because there's hundred of them,) but with it all being unsorted it's frustrating (cause there's hundreds of images.) the code on the page itself is:

```
<script src="../15x52_images/New_England/agetpics.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Dynamic PHP Picture Viewer (v1.0)- By JavaScriptKit.com (http://www.javascriptkit.com) //--->
    <!-- For this and over 400+ free scripts, visit JavaScript Kit- http://www.javascriptkit.com/ //--->
    <!-- This notice must stay intact for use //--->

    function populateSelect(selectobj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < picsarray.length; i++)
            selectobj.options[selectobj.options.length] = new Option(picsarray[i], picsarray[i])
        if (selectobj.options.length > 1) {
            selectobj.selectedIndex = 0
            showpicture(document.getElementById("picsform").picslist)
        }
    }

    function showpicture(selectobj) {
        piccontainerobj = document.getElementById("picturearea")
        resetfade(10)
        piccontainerobj.innerHTML = '<img src="' + locationstring + selectobj.options[selectobj.selectedIndex].value + '">'
        fadepictoview = setInterval("gradualfade(piccontainerobj)", 50)
    }

    function resetfade(degree) {
        if (window.fadepictoview)
            clearInterval(fadepictoview)
        if (typeof piccontainerobj.style.MozOpacity == "string")
            piccontainerobj.style.MozOpacity = degree / 100
        else if (piccontainerobj.filters)
            piccontainerobj.filters.alpha.opacity = degree
    }

    function gradualfade() {
        if (typeof piccontainerobj.style.MozOpacity == "string" && piccontainerobj.style.MozOpacity < 1)
            piccontainerobj.style.MozOpacity = Math.min(parseFloat(piccontainerobj.style.MozOpacity) + 0.2, 0.99)
        else if (piccontainerobj.filters && piccontainerobj.filters.alpha.opacity < 100)
            piccontainerobj.filters.alpha.opacity += 20
        else //if not IE or Moz
            clearInterval(fadepictoview)
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        populateSelect(document.getElementById("picsform").picslist)
    }
</script>
```

and the code in the image directory is:

```
<?php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
$pathstring     = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$locationstring = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $pathstring['dirname'] . "/";

function returnimages($dirname = ".")
{
    $pattern  = "(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)";
    //create an array to hold the directory list
    $files    = array();
    $curimage = 0;
    //create a handler for the directory
    if ($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
        //keep going until all files in directory are read
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (eregi($pattern, $file)) {
                echo 'picsarray[' . $curimage . ']="' . $file . '";';
                $curimage++;
            }
        }
        //close the handler
        closedir($handle);
    }
    //return results
    return ($files);
}

echo 'var locationstring="' . $locationstring . '";';
echo 'var picsarray=new Array();';
returnimages();
?>
```

im listing both as im not sure which one i would have to type a request to sort in, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Sorry, but that code is horrible on many levels.. If you want to sort the list, you could do this inside javascript or php.

Answer (score 2):

So you have an array of just filenames. IE, `$files[0]="foolish.jpg"` and `$files[1]="aberforth.png"`.  If sorting based on the file name is OK, simply run your array through `sort()`.  Otherwise, you'll need to expand your array to be multidimensional with each element being an associative array - or perhaps create an Image object and make an array of those.  Either way, you'll need to pull out the other things you'd like to sort on - file extension, size, date modified, etc. - and include that info so you can then build your array and then sort on it using `usort()` and your own defined sorting method.

IE,

```
$files[0]['name']="foolish.jpg";
$files[0]['size']="1678013";
$files[0]['dlm']=filetime($files[0]['name]);
```

Or instead of an array of associative arrays you can make your own ImageFile class and create an array of those objects.

Either way, you can sort via `usort()`.

**However....**

All of that would be terribly inefficient, especially as your image count increases.  It would be better to store all of this information in a database - ideally populated as images are uploaded.  For your already existing images, simply write a script to gather and insert the data once.  Or if you are uploading via scp, ftp, etc and not a web form have a cron job run every so often that re-scans the directory and adds or updates entries.

This would mitigate the extreme load you'd see as soon as more than a few clients tried connecting at one time.... and solve your problem of being able to sort. You might could even store the files themselves in the database.....